# How do I partition the right side of the Pivot while using the recursive quicksort divide and conquer algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, quicksort

I have the following issue, I am trying to implement the first partition step in the quick sort algorithm, I need to use only two arguments for the quickSortDivide function (array and size). I am have been able to sort the left side of the array and return the index of pivot for the recursive call. However, my problem is that on the right side of the pivot I am not able to sort that partition because I am not able to find the right most wall from the returned index. I hope that makes sense, please find the code below:

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int size) {


    if (size > 1) {
        
        int index = quickSortDivide(arr, size);
        std::cout << "in recursion:  " <<index <<endl;
        quickSort(arr, index-1);
        quickSort(arr, index +1);
        
    }
 

}



int quickSortDivide(int* arr, int size)
{
    

    int pivot = arr[size - 1], current, index = 0;
    cout << " piv: " << pivot <<  endl;

    for (int i = index; i < size; i++)
    {

        if (arr[i] > pivot) {
            for (int j = i; j < size; j++)
            {

                if (arr[j] < pivot) {
                   
                    index = i;
                    swapInArray(arr, i, j);

                }
            }
        }
 
    }
    swapInArray(arr, index + 1, size-1 );
    
    return index;
}
```

Output:

```
before function call { 14, 3, 1, 9, 7, 45, 10};


after function call: {1 3 7 9 10 45 14}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can juggle the arguments, but I suggest this:

```
int index = quickSortDivide(arr, size);
std::cout << "in recursion:  " << index <<endl;
quickSort(arr, index++);
quickSort(arr + index, size - index));
```

The post-increment skips past the pivot location, and the second recursion rebases the "array" starting address after that skip, reducing the segment size to be the remainder of the segment thereafter.

Note: I still see at least one more bug in your implementation, but that's for you to find.